# How to make text appear when standing over a box collider?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

So I have a box collider and I want it so when im standing over it, it shows text. Like telling you what button to press to enter. How do I do that?

Comment: Collision trigger events and showing/hiding objects is covered in a wide array of Unity tutorials, so you don't really need 1-on-1 personalized Q&A to sort this out. It sounds like you might want to ramp up on the basic engine features a bit further.

Comment: got any links? nothing

Answer (score 1):

You Can use [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html). For Example

```
public class TrigerArea : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text bubbleMessageText;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        bubbleMessageText.text = "ENTER YOU MESSAGE HERE";
    }
}
```